# How to iterate over large Cassandra table in small chunks in Spark

Tags: scala, cassandra, apache-spark, rdd

In my test environment I have 1 Cassandra node and 3 Spark nodes. I want to iterate over apparently large table that has about 200k rows, each roughly taking 20-50KB.

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  uid timeuuid,
  events blob,
  PRIMARY KEY ((uid))
)
```

Here is scala code that is executed at spark cluster

```
val rdd = sc.cassandraTable("test", "foo")

// This pulls records in memory, taking ~6.3GB
var count = rdd.select("events").count()  

// Fails nearly immediately with 
// NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed [...]
var events = rdd.select("events").collect()
```

Cassandra 2.0.9, Spark: 1.2.1, Spark-cassandra-connector-1.2.0-alpha2

I tried to only run `collect`, without `count` - in this case it just fails fast with `NoHostAvailableException`.

**Question:** what is the correct approach to iterate over large table reading and processing small batch of rows at a time?

Comment: You could try increasing the number of partitions before counting, with repartition

Answer (score 6):

There are 2 settings in the Cassandra Spark Connector to adjust the chunk size (put them in the SparkConf object):

- spark.cassandra.input.split.size: number of rows per Spark partition (default 100000)
- spark.cassandra.input.page.row.size: number of rows per fetched page (ie network roundtrip) (default 1000)

Furthermore, you shouldn't use the `collect` action in your example because it will fetch all the rows in the driver application memory and may raise an out of memory exception. You can use the `collect` action only if you know for sure it will produce a small number of rows. The `count` action is different, it produce only a integer. So I advise you to load your data from Cassandra like you did, process it, and store the result (in Cassandra, HDFS, whatever).