# spark datasax cassandra connector slow to read from heavy cassandra table

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-streaming, spark-cassandra-connector, spring-data-cassandra

I am new to Spark/ Spark Cassandra Connector. We are trying spark for the first time in our team and we are using spark cassandra connector to connect to cassandra Database.

I wrote a query which is using a heavy table of the database and I saw that Spark Task didn't start until the query to the table fetched all the records.

It is taking more than 3 hours just to fetch all the records from the database.

To get the data from the DB we use.

```
  CassandraJavaUtil.javaFunctions(sparkContextManager.getJavaSparkContext(SOURCE).sc())
    .cassandraTable(keyspaceName, tableName);
```

Is there a way to tell spark to start working even if all the data didn't finish to download ?

Is there an option to tell spark-cassandra-connector to use more threads for the fetch ?

thanks,
kokou.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the Spark UI, how many partitions is your table scan creating? I just did something like this and I found that Spark was creating too many partitions for the scan and it was taking much longer as a result. The way I decreased the time on my job was by setting the configuration parameter `spark.cassandra.input.split.size_in_mb` to a value higher than the default. In my case it took a 20 minute job down to about four minutes. There are also a couple more Cassandra read specific Spark variables that you can set found [here](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/2_loading.md).
These stackoverflow questions are what I referenced originally, I hope they help you out as well.

[Iterate large Cassandra table in small chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28726044/how-to-iterate-over-large-cassandra-table-in-small-chunks-in-spark)

[Set number of tasks on Cassandra table scan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31672860/setting-number-of-spark-tasks-on-a-cassandra-table-scan)

**EDIT:**

After doing some performance testing with regards to fiddling with some Spark configuration parameters, I found that Spark was creating far too many table partitions when I wasn't giving the Spark executors enough memory. In my case, upping the memory by a gigabyte was enough to render the input split size parameter unnecessary. If you can't give the executors more memory, you may still need to set `spark.cassandra.input.split.size_in_mb`higher as a form of workaround.